# SignUp form with custom attribute using Amplify VueJS UI

Tags: vue.js, aws-amplify

I'm looking for a way to make a SignUp form where a hidden custom attribute is attached to the new account. I can't find any documentation for this on the AWS UI Amplify docs for VueJS. I can do this with the JS library, like this

```js
Auth.signUp({
    username,
    password,
    attributes: {
        email,
        'custom:group': 'Teacher'  // custom attribute, not standard
    }
});
```

Comment: Why can't you just use this `custom:group`?

Comment: @Luke the Auth.SignUp is from the JS library, I want it to affect to the UI